Snowflake Function that returns string to be used in IN statement on Where Clause
I have created a Function in Snowflake that returns a string, its a list of numbers with a single quotes separating them.
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION LOCATIONS()
RETURNS STRING
LANGUAGE SQL
AS
$$
  '''1','2','3','4','9'''
$$;

This returns the following: '1','2','3','4','9'
I want to use this in an in Statement like:
select *
from Table
where ID in ( select LOCATIONS() )

That table, the ID column is a number format, so I did the following:
select *
from Table
where to_varchar(ID) in ( select LOCATIONS() )

If I run this, it returns 0 results. If I copy the line above from the direct output of the function (select LOCATIONS() ) it returns results for me:
select *
from Table
where to_varchar(ID) in ( '1','2','3','4','9' )

What am I missing, I am not getting errors, and everything seems to be operating as it should.
I was expecting to get results from my query, but there is nothing.

try this
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION LOCATIONS()
RETURNS TABLE (example_col varchar2(100))
LANGUAGE SQL
AS
$$
     (with data as ( SELECT * FROM VALUES ('1'),('2'),('3'),('4'),('9')) select * from data)

$$
; 

select * from table(LOCATIONS())

create table t1 (id char(20));
insert into t1  (
    SELECT * FROM VALUES ('1'),('2'),('3'),('4'));
select * from t1 where id in (select * from table(LOCATIONS()));



thank you for this solution, this solves it for me perfectly. I ultimately picked this option, over the other option below, because its a much cleaner way of doing the dynamic data in the query itself.

The first function (is invalid) but if valid it would return "one" string that has quotes and commas and digits in it. of which to_varchar(id) will never match (the only single string you have)...
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION LOCATIONS()
RETURNS STRING
LANGUAGE SQL
AS
$$
  '''1'',''2'',''3'',''4'',''9'''
$$;


where-as the explicit list of strings, is actually a completely different thing.
select $1 as id
    ,id::text as id_t
    ,id_t in ('1','2','3','4')
    ,id_t in ('''1'',''2'',''3'',''4'',''9''')
    ,id_t in (LOCATIONS())
from values
    (1),
    (4),
    (100);

gives:

So this can work if you change the string from locations to be a single string:
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION LOCATIONS()
RETURNS STRING
LANGUAGE SQL
AS
$$
  '1,2,3,4,9'
$$;

then you can SPLIT this to an array, and then use ARRAY_CONTAINS
select $1 as id
    ,id::text as id_t
    ,split(LOCATIONS(),',') as loc_s
    ,array_contains(id_t::variant, loc_s)
from values
    (1),
    (4),
    (100);


or more simply:
select $1 as id
from values
    (1),
    (4),
    (100)
where array_contains($1::text::variant, split(LOCATIONS(),','))



Thank you for this detailed explanation, this helped me learn more about how Snowflake handles the data. I will say that for my use case I did select the other option above as the answer for me because the end result that would live in the views would be much cleaner. However I tested this in my environment and it gave the exact same result. Thanks again for the detail.
